# Does any harmonic function of trace zero vanish on the boundary?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The following material is cited from the chapter of Evans' PDE book concerning Sobolev spaces.

> 

**Theorem 1.** *Let $U$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $C^1$ boundary. Then there exists a bounded linear operator $T:W^{1,p}(U)\to L^p(\partial U)$ such that*

1. *$T(u)=u|_{\partial U}$ if $u\in W^{1,p}(U)\cap C(\bar U)$.*
2. *There exists a constant $C$ such that for each $u$ in $W^{1,p}(U)$, $$\Vert T(u)\Vert_{L^p(\partial U)}\leq C\Vert u\Vert_{W^{1,p}(U)}.$$*

Denoting the closure of $C_c^\infty(U)$ in $W^{k,p}(U)$ by $W_0^{k,p}(U)$, we have:

**Theorem 2.** *A function $u$ in $W^{1,p}(U)$ falls into $W^{1,p}_0(U)$ if and only if $T(u)=0$ on $\partial U$.*

> 

From [Why is the trace operator not injective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3292804/why-is-the-trace-operator-not-injective), I see the trace operator $T$ may not be injective. Hence, if $T(u)\equiv 0$ for some $u$, I have plenty of reasons to say that $u$ may be nontrivial on $U$. But what if $u$ is a **harmonic function** with vanishing trace on $\partial U$? Is there anything I can say about its behavior on $\partial U$? Actually, I was hoping to conclude that **$\mathbf{u=0}$ on $\mathbf{\partial U}$**. Any advice is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Suppose $u \in H_0^1(U)$. From $(-\Delta u, u) = \|du\|_{L^2(U)}^2$ and Poincare inequality we get $\|\Delta u\|_{H^{-1}}^2 \geq C\|u\|_{H^1(U)}^2$. Hence $\Delta : H_0^1(U) \to H^{-1}(U)$ is injective. (In fact it is also surjective). So if $u \in H^1(U)$ and $u|_{\partial U} = 0$, then since $U$ has $C^1$ boundary we get $u \in H_0^1(U)$, so we can apply the above result.

Comment: @Mason Thank you, but why did you **assume** $u|_{\partial U} = 0$? Is it an assertion that we try to **confirm**?

Comment: You asked what happens if $u$ is harmonic on $U$ and has vanishing trace. The trace of $u$ is denoted $u|_{\partial U}$.

Comment: @Mason Thank you.